# Is it possible to only infer some generic in a function call?

Tags: typescript

In this example, why `T` cannot be inferred?

```
declare function test<S, T>(param1: T);
test<string>(1);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=declare%20function%20test%3CS%2C%20T%3E(param1%3A%20T)%3B%0D%0Atest%3Cstring%3E(1)%3B)

Comment: What is your original problem? What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: I have an API which internally keep an object which have "static properties" and "runtime properties" where static properties are defined by user in module context and runtime properties could be supplied by user later. The full list of properties are known but which is static and which is runtime is unknown, I wanted to use typescript to ensure that the runtime supplied properties are not already supplied in module context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current implementation of generic function argument inference is all-or-nothing - there is no provision for supplying only some of the type arguments and inferring missing ones.

There is [work in progress](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26349) to support it (see also [the proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242)), currently on roadmap for the next release (3.3), however I remember it was also scheduled for 3.2 and did not make it.

The workaround that you could use in the meantime is currying:

```
declare function test<S>(): <T>(param1: T) => void;

test<string>()(1);
```

Comment: That part about currying workaround is cool, but I always find currying ugly :(

Comment: Thanks. Glad to know it is work in progress. I thought about the currying solution too but that requires me to change my API too much. I will wait for TS to implement this then.